# How do I reduce height between sections in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using Microsoft Word 2013 on a Windows 8 computer.

I want to be able to tighten the sections that are in my Word document. 
How would I go about doing that?

I know the Paragraph Spacing tool helped a little. But not enough. And it's probably the wrong tool anyway, since it is not paragraphs I want to tighten up, but action design sections on the page. Am I thinking more along the lines of margins?

[image: Word Screenshot to reduce size]

Comment: It would be more helpful to show sample text instead of blurring it, it's a bit difficult to understand your situation now. Also first "reduce" arrows: what exactly do you want to reduce there? From the current screenshot I think you need to change paragraph settings: spacing before & after, line spacing. Also, why there is the manual line break at the end of "software skills" instead of paragraph mark? I'm not aware of "section break" settings in Word

Comment: Good questions.  I just want to change the space height between each section, not paragraphs.

Comment: as I've already written, no such settings exists. So the only way to reduce it is to reduce around your paragraphs. Also, there is no section break between your second and third "reduce", that spacing is not coming from section break.